# How Fix My Script Error: "Object doesn't support property or method 'modal' "

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the follow error on my site when I click on the "Email Company" link (an example is here: http://www.expeditionersafaris.com/place/5-day-best-of-both-worlds-kruger-and-private-reserve-tour-wildlife-encounters/).

The error is:

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'modal' 
post.custom.js, line 56 character 3

The script is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('a.b_sendtofriend').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#basic-modal-content').modal({persist:true});
});

jQuery('a.b_claim_listing').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#basic-modal-content4').modal({persist:true});
});

    jQuery('a.b_send_inquiry' ).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#basic-modal-content2').modal({persist:true});
});

    jQuery('p.links a.a_image_sort').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#basic-modal-content3').modal({persist:true});
});
```

The error is pointing to the jQuery('#basic-modal-content2').modal({persist:true}); portion.

Comment: I think you need to apply a certain class to the html elements for modal to work on them

Comment: You can't call `.modal()` if it doesn't exist. To fix it, you need to provide that method.

Comment: You're missing a plugin that defines `modal()`.